# Flatten a Multilevel Doubly Linked List leetcode

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

You are given a doubly linked list which in addition to the next and previous pointers, it could have a child pointer, which may or may not point to a separate doubly linked list. These child lists may have one or more children of their own, and so on, to produce a multilevel data structure, as shown in the example below.

Flatten the list so that all the nodes appear in a single-level, doubly linked list. You are given the head of the first level of the list.[image]

```
class Solution {
/*Global variable pre to track the last node we visited */
    Node pre = null;
    public Node flatten(Node head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return null; 
        }
/*Connect last visted node with current node */
        if (pre != null) {
            pre.next = head; 
            head.prev = pre;
        }

        pre = head; 
/*Store head.next in a next pointer in case recursive call to flatten head.child overrides head.next*/
        Node next = head.next; 

        flatten(head.child);
        head.child = null;

        flatten(next);        
        return head; 
    }
}
```

For the question, the above leetcode solution works. But I don't understand this:

```
/*Store head.next in a next pointer in case recursive call to flatten head.child overrides head.next*/
        Node next = head.next;
```

Can anyone explain this part? How does the head.child override head.next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatten(head.child)` may change `head.next` due to the part where we connect last visited node with the current node:

```java
if (pre != null) {
  pre.next = head; 
  head.prev = pre;
}
```

At this stage, `pre` represents older `head` and `head` represents `head.child`. So we actually connect our `head` with its `child`. But if we do so, we will lose our connection to the actual `head.next`, therefore we have to keep it in an extra variable called `next`. That's why we keep it before calling the `flatten()` function.